# Deploying Flask on VPS

Tags: python, deployment, frameworks, mod-wsgi, flask

I currently have a LAMP stack on a Linode VPS.

My server is set up with apache2, and then in /etc/apache2/sites-available I have a list of site vhosts.

Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin user@gmail.com
     ServerName domain.com
     ServerAlias www.domain.com
     DocumentRoot /folder/www/domain.com/public_html/
     ErrorLog /folder/www/domain.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /folderx/www/domain.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm primarily a PHP developer, but I'm trying to get into Python with Flask.

As per the instructions [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/), I'm installed mod_wsgi. But, I'm a little confused as to how to do the rest. Create the wsgi file, create a new Flask application, etc.

Are there any good tutorials, or could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#quickstart

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/#tutorial

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/#creating-a-wsgi-file

If this stuff is all really new to you, you should not worry about mod_wsgi initially and just use the builtin development server of Flask and play with it on your own local box. This is not PHP. You do not need to install Apache just to be able to do stuff.

Comment: I looked at the first and second, but couldn't figure out what to put inside the wsgi file. My thing is that I don't like playing in local boxes. I would prefer just deploying and editing on the server. I only have Apache installed because I'm a PHP developer...

Comment: Is not the URL of the third obvious enough where it says 'creating-a-wsgi-file'? You really need to go through the standalone tutorial first to understand how Flask works. If you don't you will just waste a lot or your time and everyone else's time as well.